# Getting Secure Websockets working on Tornado

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

How to set WSS (Secure WebSockets) on Tornado?

In their docstring, they say the following:

`WebSocketHandler.get_websocket_scheme` can be used to select the
appropriate url scheme (`ws://` or `wss://`) in cases where  `HTTPRequest.protocol` is not set correctly.

So, how can I use `get_websocket_scheme` and/or `HTTPRequest.protocol` to get the WSS to work on Tornado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it :))

Just add this to your application:

```
   http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application,ssl_options={
    "certfile": "cert.cer",
    "keyfile":  "key.key",
})
```

This will solve the problem. Just very similar to regular HTTPS.
I also appreciate any other way to make it work.

Comment: i am not sure if it's a certificate issue. but when i am trying to connect ssl over secure websocket and https. it's working in html & java script environment. but when i created a client in python script. it showing me certificate verification failed.
I posted a question over stackoverflow as  well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852066/how-to-create-python-secure-websocket-client-request. could you please advise? it's bit urgent.

Comment: I posted a comment there .. let me know if resolves your problem.