# How to create Python secure websocket client request?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, openssl, tornado, azure-web-app-service

My Python secure websocket client code giving me exception as follows:

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)

I have created my private certificate and and sign certificate as well, but I am not able to connect to it using Python script as follows:

```
import json
from websocket import create_connection


class subscriber:
   def listenForever(self):
   try:
      # ws = create_connection("wss://localhost:9080/websocket")
      ws = create_connection("wss://nbtstaging.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:9090/websocket")
      ws.send("test message")
      while True:
          result = ws.recv()
          result = json.loads(result)
          print("Received '%s'" % result)

      ws.close()
  except Exception as ex:
      print("exception: ", format(ex))


try:
    subscriber().listenForever()
except:
    print("Exception occured: ")
```

My https/wss server script in python with tornado as follows:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import os
import ssl

ssl_root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ssl1_1020')


class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message("Your message was: " + message)
        print("message received: ", format(message))

    def on_close(self):
        pass


class IndexPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
           (r'/', IndexPageHandler),
           (r'/websocket', WebSocketHandler),
        ]

        settings = {
            'template_path': 'templates'
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain(ssl_root+"/server.crt",
                    ssl_root + "/server.pem")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ws_app = Application()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(ws_app, ssl_options=ssl_ctx,)
    server.listen(9081, "0.0.0.0")
    print("server started...")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

steps used to create SSL signed certificates:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.pem
openssl req -new -nodes -key server.pem -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.pem -out server.crt
```

Comment: Do you use MacOS? It's more likely a problem with the system permissions, you might need to add the certificate to the keychain ... you may want to check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691327/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c

Comment: No, it's all Linux ubuntu 16.04 env os.

Comment: Someone with similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, I updated python client script while making connection to secure web socket url to ignore cert request as follows:

```
 import ssl
 import websocket

 ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
 ws.connect("wss://xxx.com:9090/websocket")
```

Answer (score 19):

For me, ignoring the errors is not an options, I had to use my self signed certificate because of SSL pinning in a complex IoT environment:

```
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl
import websockets

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
localhost_pem = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("localhost.pem")
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(localhost_pem)

async def hello():
    uri = "wss://localhost:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(
        uri, ssl=ssl_context
    ) as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send(name)
        print(f"> {name}")

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Found it [here](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/34aaf6bcbbac62d8c605d5ba768709346ef87c6e/example/secure_client.py) on the websocket repo's examples folder.

#### P.S

I changed it from `SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)` to `SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)` to make it work

Comment: Finally, this works for me after trying to fix the error for 3 days. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is curious in the future why wss python server fails is because of this right here in the tornado documentation:

> When using a secure websocket connection (wss://) with a self-signed certificate, the connection from a browser may fail because it wants to show the “accept this certificate” dialog but has nowhere to show it. You must first visit a regular HTML page using the same certificate to accept it before the websocket connection will succeed.

Comment: For example, if the websocket is on `localhost:4000`, you would have to visit `https://localhost:4000` and accept the risk.

Answer (score 3):

Only try the below for testing purposes only. The below is a highly insecure kluge:

```
import asyncio, ssl, websockets

#todo kluge
#HIGHLY INSECURE
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext()
ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
#HIGHLY INSECURE
#todo kluge

uri = "wss://myAwesomeSSL.wss.kluge"

async with websockets.connect(uri, ssl=ssl_context) as websocket:
        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that most answers are suggesting disabling TLS verification which is not ideal.

Here's a working example, with TLS verification **enabled**, which I think it's what should be done by default, unless you work on localhost or similar.

```py
import asyncio
import certifi
import ssl
import websockets


async def wss_connect(url):

    # Define an SSL context that will connect to TLS 1.2+ servers
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
    ssl_context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3

    # Load the certificates authorities via the certifi library 
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(certifi.where())

    async with websockets.connect(url, ssl=ssl_context) as websocket:
        await websocket.send("hello!")
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {response}")
        return response


uri = "wss://yourhost.wss.example/api/v1/test"
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(wss_connect(uri))
```