# Python requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'wss://localhost:6868 while connecting web socket using jsonrpc

Tags: python, websocket, json-rpc

```
import requests
payload = {"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getCortexInfo"}
r = requests.get( 'wss://localhost:6868' , params = payload)
print(r.text)
```

> error message :raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))

> requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'wss://localhost:6868'

**Can anyone provide a alternative solution**

Comment: `requests` is not suitable to connect to a websocket.

Comment: The `requests` module , does not support `websockets` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852066/how-to-create-python-secure-websocket-client-request) answer instead.